# Why does Stroustrup's std_lib_facilities.h modify the input size of the operator[] with std::vector?

Tags: c++

Here's an excerpt from the current std_lib_facilities.h (from [his website](http://stroustrup.com/Programming)):

```
...

// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
    using std::vector<T>::vector;   // inheriting constructor

    T& operator[](unsigned int i)   // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||this->size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};

// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
...
```

I have a couple questions about this:

1. I believe that the paramater for `operator[]` is normally `size_type` (which itself is normally `size_t`) so why change to `unsigned int`?
2. Since `i` is defined here as `unsigned int`, the comparison `i < 0` is always false, no?  And if that is true, why make the comparison?

I noticed this after enabling `-Wconversion` with gcc and using code from his book:

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<double>temps;
    for (double temp; cin >> temp; )
        temps.push_back(temp);

    // compute mean temperature:
    double sum = 0;
    for (auto x : temps) sum += x;
    cout << "Average temperature: " << sum / temps.size() << '\n';

    // compute median temperature:
    sort(begin(temps), end(temps));        
    cout << "Median temperature: " << temps[temps.size()/2] << '\n';

    keep_window_open();  

    return 0;
}
```

Since `temps.size()` returns a `size_type` a conversion warning/error occurs with `temps[temps.size()/2]`.

Comment: Why don't you ask him personally? After all anything we could do is speculate, no?

Comment: I suppose it is speculation, but I'm assuming there is a good reason for him to do so and that someone more familiar with c++ could explain why.

Comment: I assume it's `unsigned int` because his students won't reach > 4 billion elements. Also I think he's checking for < 0 out of habit he might have. It's all speculative.

Comment: I updated the question with code from his book that issues a warning when gcc's `-Wconversion` flag is used.  This seems like something desirable for beginners, no?  Indexes aren't always simple constants and using the collection's size in a computation seems quite reasonable.